# Set Content-Type to application/json in jsp file

Tags: java, http, jsp, http-headers, content-type

I am created some jsp file that returns as a response some json string. But I see that the Content-Type is set to txt automatically

My jsp code looks like

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Random" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<%
  String retVal = "// some json string";

     int millis = new Random().nextInt(1000);
     //    System.out.println("sleeping for " + millis + " millis");
     Thread.sleep(millis);
%>
<%=retVal%>
```

How can I perform something like

```
setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

in this example?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can do via [Page directive](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm7.html).

For example:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

- contentType="mimeType [ ;charset=characterSet ]" |
  "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"

> The MIME type and character encoding the JSP file uses for the
>   response it sends to the client. You can use any MIME type or
>   character set that are valid for the JSP container. The default MIME
>   type is text/html, and the default character set is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 12):

Try this piece of code, it should work too

```
<%
    //response.setContentType("Content-Type", "application/json"); // this will fail compilation
    response.setContentType("application/json"); //fixed
%>
```

Comment: but this  throws exception like java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Comment: make sure you do *not output any single character* to the client before calling `setContentType(..)` (otherwise the content type is already fixed before that). Especially pay attention to spaces or newlines after %>, e.g. write move the closing %> of the first line to the second line and start immediately with the next <% immediately after it etc.

Answer (score 3):

@Petr Mensik & kensen john

Thanks, I could not used the page directive because I have to set a different content type according to some URL parameter. I will paste my code here since it's something quite common with JSON:

```
    <%
        String callback = request.getParameter("callback");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        if (callback != null) {
            // Equivalent to: <@page contentType="text/javascript" pageEncoding="UTF-8">
            response.setContentType("text/javascript");
        } else {
            // Equivalent to: <@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8">
            response.setContentType("application/json");
        }
    
        [...]
    
        String output = "";
    
        if (callback != null) {
            // IMPORTANT! Sanitise the "callback",
            // do not use user input directly in the response!
            // This is vulnerable to XSS attacks.
            output += callback + "(";
        }
    
        output += jsonObj.toString();
    
        if (callback != null) {
            output += ");";
        }
    %>
    <%=output %>
```

When callback is supplied, returns:

```
    callback({...JSON stuff...});
```

with content-type "text/javascript"

When callback is NOT supplied, returns:

```
    {...JSON stuff...}
```

with content-type "application/json"

[EDIT] I'm reviewing my old post. If you use this solution, please sanitise your input! It's dangerous to put user input string directly in the response.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for something like this